# What should i do to put dash along the question itself?

Tags: rules

I need to give a answer line along the question. what should I do?

That is if I have a question like this..

```
The value of $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=______________$
```

What should I do to put dash along the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\rule` command like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
The value of $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=\rule{60pt}{1pt}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your question, you want to obtain something similar to the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

%The value of $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=______________$

\noindent
\hbox to\linewidth{The value of $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=\hrulefill$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would suggest rather `...\theta={}\hrulefill...` for better spacing around `=` sign.

Comment: oh.. i may be not clear.. I need the answer what vahid Posted. @Przemyslaw

Comment: @David So exactly what I made: an underscore to the end of a line. Or I am missing something?